# Django CMS cms_plugin setup for a message form to send an email is not working

Tags: django, django-cms

I've setup a django cms site for a friend so that he can easily swap pictures out and do much of the work from the front-end. It's a very simple site and working great, but I have a page called 'contacts' using it's own cms template with a placeholder for the contact_form with the key component being a message form that sends the content as an email, this functionality is the reason I need to pull the form in as a plugin from the utilities app.

It works great as a standalone django page, if the form is valid, it sends the email and a success message pops up as a bootstrap 5 alert advising it was sent; if the form isn't valid, an error message pops up instead. In the cms plugin however, I can add it in and it looks fine on the page but none of the functionality provided by the utilities/views/contact_form works and it doesn't appear to use the view functionality at all apart from drawing the template location from it. I've tested this with including print() at a few places in the utilities/views.py file.

Any advice on how to ensure the full functionality of the contact form would be greatly appreciated. The relevant files are provided below.

Many thanks!

### utilities/forms.py

```
from django import forms

# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/fields/#widget
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    error_css_class = "error"
    required_css_class = "required"
    name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter your name...'}),
        help_text='A name is required.'
    )
    email = forms.EmailField(
        max_length=100,
        widget= forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder':'name@example.com'}),
        help_text='A valid email address is required.'
    )
    phone = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'xxxx xxxxxx'}),
        help_text='A phone number is required.'
    )
    message = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter your message...'}),
        help_text='A message is required.'
    )
```

### utilities/views.py file:

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ContactForm


def contact_form(request):
    template_name = 'utilities/contact_form.html'
    form = ContactForm(
        request.POST or None,
    )
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    if request.method =='POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            message = '''
                New Message: {}
                
                From: {}            
            '''.format(data['message'], data['email'])
            send_mail(data['subject'], message, '', ['philobrien@gmail.com'])
            messages.success(
                request,
                "Your message has been sent to Phil and he'll get back to you soon.",
                fail_silently=True,
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/utilities/contact-form/')
        else:
            messages.warning(
                request,
                'Your message had errors, please complete the form and submit again.',
                fail_silently=True,
            )
            return render(request, template_name, context)

    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

### utilities/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import *

app_name = 'utilities'

urlpatterns = [
    path('contact-form/', contact_form, name='contact-form'),
]
```

### utilities/templates/utilities/contact_form.html

This had a little more in it when using in the app as a stand-alone from cms but I brought it back to this for implmenting into a cms plugin

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<div class="row gx-5 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <!-- Contact form-->
        <div class="bg-light rounded-3 py-5 px-4 px-md-5 mb-5">
            <div class="text-center mb-5 text-dark">
                <div class="feature bg-primary bg-gradient rounded-3 mb-3"><i class="bi bi-envelope"></i></div>
                <h1 class="fw-bolder">Get in touch</h1>
                <p class="lead fw-normal text-muted mb-0">Start a conversation about that project you've been wanting to get started on. Phil would love to hear from you!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row gx-5 justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-xl-6">
                    <form id="contactForm" action="" method="Post" class="">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <!-- Name input-->
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3 text-dark">
                             {{ form.name | as_crispy_field }}
                        </div>
                        <!-- Email address input-->
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3 text-dark">
                             {{ form.email | as_crispy_field }}
                        </div>
                        <!-- Phone number input-->
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3 text-dark">
                             {{ form.phone | as_crispy_field }}
                        </div>
                        <!-- Message input-->
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3 text-dark">
                             {{ form.message | as_crispy_field }}
                        </div>
                        <!-- Submit Button-->
                        <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### utilities_cms_integrations/models.py

```
from cms.models import CMSPlugin
from django.db import models

class ContactFormPluginModel(CMSPlugin):
    title = models.CharField(u'title',
        blank=True,
        help_text=u'Optional. Title of the widget.',
        max_length=64,
    )
```

### utilities_cms_plugins.cms_plugins.py

```
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import ContactFormPluginModel
from utilities.forms import ContactForm


@plugin_pool.register_plugin
class ContactPluginModel(CMSPluginBase):
    model = ContactFormPluginModel
    module = _("Utilities")
    name = _("Contact Form Plugin")
    render_template = "utilities/contact_form.html"

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        try:
            path = context['request'].path
        except:
            path = ''

        print('Context: ', context)
        print('Path: ', path)
        # form = ContactForm(initial={'referer':path})
        form = ContactForm(initial={'referer': 'utilities:contact-form'})
        # form = ContactForm(request.POST or None,)
        context.update({
            "title": instance.title,
            "form": form,
            "form_action": reverse('utilities:contact-form'),
        })
        return context
```

In the root app, I have the following files:

### root/templates/components/base.html

```
{% load cms_tags menu_tags sekizai_tags i18n static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="{% page_attribute 'meta_description' %}"/>
        <meta name="author" content=""/>
        <title>Caldera Bespoke - {% page_attribute 'title' %}</title>
        <!-- Favicon-->
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static 'assets/racing_25.ico' %}"/>
        <!-- Bootstrap icons-->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
        <link href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
        {% render_block 'css' %}
        {% block extra_head %}
        {% endblock extra_head %}
    </head>
    <body class="d-flex flex-column">
         <main class="flex-shrink-0">
            <!-- Navigation-->
             {% cms_toolbar %}
             {% include 'menu/navbar.html' %}
             <!-- Messages-->
            {% include 'components/messages.html' %}
            <!-- Page content-->
             {% block content %}
             {% endblock content %}
         </main>
        <!-- Footer-->
        {% include 'menu/footer.html' %}
        <!-- Bootstrap core JS-->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Core theme JS-->
        <script src="{% static 'js/scripts.js' %}"></script>
        {% render_block 'js' %}
        {% block extra_body %}
        {% endblock extra_body %}
    </body>
</html>
```

### root/templates/menu/navbar.html

```
{% load menu_tags %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark border-bottom">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Caldera Bespoke</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                {% show_menu 0 1 0 1 "menu/menu.html" %}
            </ul>
            <div class="ms_auto">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'account_logout' %}">logout</a>
                    {% else %}
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'account_login' %}">login</a>
                    {% endif %}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

### root/templates/components/messages.html

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}" role="alert">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

### root/templates/contact.html

```
{% load cms_tags menu_tags sekizai_tags i18n static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="{% page_attribute 'meta_description' %}"/>
        <meta name="author" content=""/>
        <title>Caldera Bespoke - {% page_attribute 'title' %}</title>
        <!-- Favicon-->
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static 'assets/racing_25.ico' %}"/>
        <!-- Bootstrap icons-->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
        <link href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
        {% render_block 'css' %}
        {% block extra_head %}
        {% endblock extra_head %}
    </head>
    <body class="d-flex flex-column">
         <main class="flex-shrink-0">
            <!-- Navigation-->
             {% cms_toolbar %}
             {% include 'menu/navbar.html' %}
             <!-- Messages-->
            {% include 'components/messages.html' %}
            <!-- Page content-->
             {% block content %}
             {% endblock content %}
         </main>
        <!-- Footer-->
        {% include 'menu/footer.html' %}
        <!-- Bootstrap core JS-->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Core theme JS-->
        <script src="{% static 'js/scripts.js' %}"></script>
        {% render_block 'js' %}
        {% block extra_body %}
        {% endblock extra_body %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm tech lead for the django-cms association, so let me shed some light on this.

In django-cms, we have plugins, and "apphooks". Plugins get added to placeholders within your pages as you've described.

You can do what you want from a plugin. You can add all the logic to the `render()` and use a `get_render_template()` method if you need to provide different templates. An example of how to do this can be found [here](https://github.com/juliarizza/djangocms_contact_form/blob/master/cmsplugin_contact_form/cms_plugins.py).

But when you want to use views, you need what we call an apphook. These allow you to link a django application to a given page within the CMS and you'll find an option for this amongst the advanced settings for a page.

The "how to" docs for apphooks can be found [here](https://djangocms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how_to/apphooks/).

When you add an apphook to a page, the URLs for the given app are then accessible from the path of the page.

To add an apphook configuration to your django apps, you need a file called `cms_apps.py`. And this needs to define how the application works;

```
from cms.app_base import CMSApp
from cms.apphook_pool import apphook_pool
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class MyApphook(CMSApp):
    name = _("My Apphook")

    def get_urls(self, page=None, language=None, **kwargs):
        return ["myapp.urls"]       # replace this with the path to your application's URLs module

apphook_pool.register(MyApphook)
```

A complex application that uses apphooks and plugins is [djangocms-blog](https://github.com/nephila/djangocms-blog/tree/develop). Looking over this may be quite useful.

Comment: super helpful Mark the blog really helped. Many thanks for the detailed response!